# Is it normal in skeletal animation to NOT consider the translation component in bone transform matrices?

Tags: directx, directx11, matrix, skeletal-animation

I'm using assimp to load a model, and DirectX11 and DirectX ToolKit to render it.

In [the document](https://directxtk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IEffectSkinning&referringTitle=Effects) of DirectXTK's IEffectSkinning, it says:

> As an optimization, SkinnedEffect and DGSLEffect assume that all the
>   matrices are affine transformations, and that the final column is (0 0
>   0 1). This means that the value of the last column is effectively
>   ignored when set into the constant buffer containing the bone
>   transformations (i.e. the shaders use float4x3)

Is this the convention when implementing skeletal animation ?

Does it have negative repercussions ? If it does, what are they ?
Do some animated models require the translation components to be considered?